# setting up angular routes

Tags: angularjs, routes

There are so many ways to set up an angular app. I've picked one, but I'm now having trouble getting the routes set up.

index.html:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    ...other files
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/routes.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainController">
    ...etc.
```

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [ "ngRoute","ui.bootstrap" ]);

    myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        //etc.
    }]);
```

This is how I usually set up my controllers, with the function wrapper:

routes.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

            $stateProvider
                .state('index', {
                    url: '/',
                    templateUrl: '../index.html',
                    controller: 'mainController',
                    controllerAs: 'mainVm',
                    data: { pageTitle: 'Main' }
                })
        }]);
})();
```

I am getting the injection error, so clearly I have missed something:

```
angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%…3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FCanada%2Fplugins%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A179)
at angular.js:38
at angular.js:4640
at q (angular.js:321)
at g (angular.js:4601)
at cb (angular.js:4523)
at c (angular.js:1758)
at Bc (angular.js:1779)
at fe (angular.js:1664)
at angular.js:31763
at HTMLDocument.b (angular.js:3207)
```

The code was working *until* I added the routing. So it's unlikely to be something elsewhere in my code.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please provide log after this line `Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:`

Answer (score 0):

You're importing the `ngRoute` module yet using `$stateProvider` which comes from the `ui-router` module. You should really be using one or the other, but certainly not both.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ["ngRoute", "ui.bootstrap"]);
```

Should be:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ["ui.router", "ui.bootstrap"]);
```

Make sure that you also include a `angular-ui-router.js` script import in your index.html before your `app.js` script import.

Comment: OK, fixing that seems to make no difference though.

Comment: Have you included the script import for `ui-router`?

Comment: I dropped angular-ui-router.js in my folder and made a reference to it. I must have had it in the wrong place. Hard to debug.